# Where is the power steering leak coming from

Tags: hyundai, leak, power-steering, santa-fe

I have a 2002 hydundai Santa Fe so last Friday my car was doing fine no problem turning or nothing didn't go no where Saturday but Sunday when I went down the road I realized it was kinda hard to turn so I filled it up and within the next few minutes it was all gone. Why is that ?

Comment: How could we possibly know where the leak is? You are best advised to get a professional diagnosis at a local reputable repair shop.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! At a minimum, you could look to see where it is draining out on the ground and look up to see where it's leaking from there. While we would love to help you, power steering fluid could be leaking from any hose or any portion of the steering system where the fluid flows to ... there is no simple answer without witnessing the issue.